# How to get a Vimeo external link

Tags: vimeo

To embed a Vimeo video as a background video, I see in this code pen:

https://codepen.io/BRacicot/pen/JpLmqo

that video source url is an special type with "external" word:

```
https://player.vimeo.com/external/243924757.hd.mp4?s=1fc7fe8bd116cdd9c9c3e639ddbae75f2f4f8f2e&profile_id=174
```

How can I get this url type from my own videos?

Comment: Try doing the same from your own videos

Comment: It doesn't work. Seems like it need something like a linked hash in the url

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That "external" link is returned in the video response, along with download links.

To get the direct file links for videos on your account, make an authenticated request to `GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos/[video_id]`. Two keys are returned in the response: `files` and `download`. The `files` key contains links and related metadata to all the files for the requested video. These links are meant for use with external/third-party media players and do not expire. The `download` key contains links to the files as well as the expiration time and related metadata for those links.

Both the files and download links are HTTP 302 redirects to the actual video file resources. The location of the actual video file resources expires every few hours, so make sure you always use the redirect links exactly as provided.

Be sure that your requests are authenticated with a token that has the `video_files` scope. If you authenticate with a token that does not have `video_files` scope, the video response will not contain `files` or `download` metadata. Vimeo API authentication docs are found here:

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#understanding-auth-workflows

Also be aware that these video file links are only returned for Vimeo Pro, Premium, and Business members:

https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224823567-Third-party-player-links

Finally, note that you may not need all of this, as the embedded Vimeo Player can be used as a chromeless background video player:

https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011183028-Embedding-background-and-chromeless-videos

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

As a Vimeo Pro user I felt the need to reach out to Vimeo Support on this given the lack of clarity in their documentation (it's 2023 and they still recommend using PHP 7.2 & Python 2)...

Below is their response, but the TLDR is that the external URL formatting is legacy, save yourself time and headache with the API and get your progressive playback links via steps described here: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224823567-Direct-links-to-video-files#h_01FKKQMFZ4YBS1SZPSM9A82VWF

---

> Thanks for your patience.
>
> The `"external"` naming in the links has been deprecated a while back.
>
> You can retrieve the video links for playback and download using the /Videos the API endpoint. https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos/3.4#get_video
>
> > `GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}`
>
> For Playback and player links, you will need to use the "files" key, ex.
>
> > `GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}?fields=files`
>
> This also includes the HLS link for use with 3rd party players that support HLS, the "play" key can be used to retrieve expiring playback links. For downloading your video you will need to use the "download" key.